# Is Dharma Sastha mentioned in Upapuranas & other Samhitas from Skanda Purana?

Tags: reference-request, skanda-purana, ayyappa, upapuranas

I heard many times that Sastha mentioned in various Puranas. But, only Brahmanda Purana and Sankara Samhita of Skanda Purana mentiones him, however it also made some sense that he can mention in Upa Puranas.

Moreover, i also wanted to know about the Samhita sections (other than Sankara Samhita) from Skanda Purana.

So my question is, Did Dharma sastha mentioned in Upa Puranas & other Samhita from Skanda Purana? Or at least they mentioned the word "Sastha"?